# How to use numbers as attributes in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have a .csv file that has numbers as column names. I want to import that file to a table in PostgreSQL, but it gives an error.

I have 1024 columns so I can't manually change it in my file. Is there a way around that?

This is the Excel file that I got:

[image]

Comment: `create table foo ("1" integer, "2" integer, ...)` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: Please edit your question and include the entire text of the error message. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a table with 1024 columns you are doing something wrong.

You should choose a different data model.

But it is possible to use numbers as column names, as long as you surround them with double quotes.

Comment: I agree. This smells funny (bad). 1,024 columns?!? Each named as just a sequential number? But wrapping them in quotes, or possibly ticks (`), should allow for this.

Comment: I can't do anything about the data model. It is the raw data that I receive from a Hyperspectral Camera. I've altered my post to show what the Excel file looks like. Anyway, putting the numbers between " " did the trick for me! I'm still a beginner when it comes to postgreSQL